# How can i get data in real time from the server to update my chartjs graph?

Tags: javascript, php, html, charts

I'm using chartjs to display live streaming data from the server i have used ajax with php to get data every second but i think this not the best idea. here is my javascript code.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON({
    url: "http://localhost/chartJS/data.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var player = [];
      var score = [];

      $.each(data, function(key, value){
        player.push("Player "+value[0]);
        score.push(parseInt(value[1]));
       });

      var chartdata = {
        labels: player,
        datasets : [
          {
            label: 'Player Score',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            data: score
          }
        ]
      };

      var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

      var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: chartdata
      });
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }});
 updateChart();
});

function updateChart()
{
  var x=2;
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON({
    url: "http://localhost/chartJS/data.php?x="+x,
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var player = [];
      var score = [];

      $.each(data, function(key, value){
        player.push("Player "+value[0]);
        score.push(value[1]);
       });
      var chartdata = {
        labels: player,
        datasets : [
          {
            label: 'Player Score',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            data: score
          }
        ]
      };

      var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

      var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: chartdata,
      });
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
setTimeout(function(){updateChart()}, 1000);
}
```

i've heard about websocket but i don't really know if i should use it or not 
and if yes how can i get the data continuously every time i open the chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is interval:

> The **setInterval()** method calls a function or evaluates an expression
>   at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

Example:

```
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

It triggers an alert every 3 seconds.

So in your case, just set an ajax call inside the interval and call it every 1000 miliseconds and then modify the graph with the new data.

Comment: you mean i replace  the setTimeout function with this one

Comment: @Riccardoperreira Yes, that by the way, setTimeout only triggers one time, how it was working?